# Objective-C/THEOS - Is it possible to save a NSMallocBlock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

When hooking a certain method a parameter is passed through that is a NSMallocBlock. I need to save this value to use it later when recalling the method from my code. I tried to save it to a user default, but this causes the program to crash. Is there anyway to save the object or recreate it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, blocks **cannot** be persisted.

```
@interface AwesomeClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, nullability) returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes);

@end
```

(block syntax via [How Do I Declare A Block in Objective-C?](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com))

The will allow you to keep a reference to your block for later in your program's execution. Note that you should always use `copy` as most blocks are initialised on the stack. Weird things happen if you don't.

As an aside, `NSUserDefaults` is designed for persisting small amounts of data between executions of your program. `-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]` only supports `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. It will generally crash if you try to set it to any other type of object. More details can be found here: [setObject:forKey: - NSUserDefaults | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414067-setobject?language=objc).

Comment: To be very clear about this answer: blocks cannot be stored. (Saying "natively" suggests there's some "non-native" way to do it, but there isn't. Blocks cannot be stored.)

Comment: @RobNapier very good point. I've reordered the post to make that very clear (hopefully).